# $\lim_{ n\to \infty} \frac{n^{100}}{1.01^n} = ?$ And how to prove it？

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, asymptotics

There are many such similar limits. But it seems that each of the proof is isolated, there are any good ways to solve it?

Comment: Hint: what would happen were you to apply L'Hopital's rule 100 times?

Comment: Many ways. The simplest (maybe) being applying L'Hopital rule a hundred time (literally)

Comment: Please also put the question in the body itself of your post.

Comment: According to WolframAlpha the answer is 0:http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x-%3Einfinity+((x%5E100)%2F(1.01%5Ex))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *good way* to find this is to have some experience with asymptotic growth rates and know that **any exponential function eventually outgrows any polynomial** (if the exponential function is increasing at all).

This immediately tells us that your limit is $0$.

If you *don't* have this knowledge already, exercises like this are exactly designed to give it to you. A reasonably painless way to see the result is to take the logarithm:
$$ \log\frac{n^{100}}{1.01^n} = 100 \log n - n \log(1.01) $$
The slope of $100\log n$ is $\frac{100}{n}$, which goes to $0$. So eventually $n$ will get large enough that the slope of $n\mapsto 100\log n$ is smaller than, say, half of $\log(1.01)$, and then it can only be a matter of time before the logarithm gets (and stays) below any desired negative value.

Since the logarithm of $\frac{n^{100}}{1.01^n}$ goes towards $-\infty$, the fraction itself goes to $0$.

---

Note that on its way to $0$, the fraction $\frac{n^{100}}{1.01^n}$ does reach values as high as about $10^{356}$, around $n=10^4$.

Comment: log refers to ln？In fact, no big difference.

Comment: @BerkeleyJones: You can use any logarithm you want -- the precise statement about the derivative of $100\log n$ being $\frac{100}{n}$ is only true for the natural logarithm, but all logarithms have slopes that go to zero in the same way, just with different multipliers.

Answer (score 2):

Write $n=1.01^{\log_{1.01}n}$ to then get the reformulation
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {1.01^{100\log_{1.01}n} }{1.01^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}1.01^{100\log_{1.01}(n)-n}=1.01^{\lim_{n\to\infty}(100\log_{1.01}(n)-n)}=0$$
This simply follows from $n $ "increasing faster" than $100\log_{1.01}(n)$ for large $n $ (the difference of their derivatives tends to infinity) making $\lim_{n\to\infty}(100\log_{1.01}(n)-n)=-\infty $.

Comment: "increasing faster" --- $f'(x) > g'(x)$ for large $x$ does not imply that $f-g \to \infty$. See $f(x) = x + 1 - e^{-x}$, $g(x) = x$.

Comment: Okay. To patch that just use that fact that $f'(x)-g'(x) $ is unbounded. The conclusion then follows.

Answer (score 1):

If you know about series, then apply the ratio test to $\displaystyle \sum \frac{n^{100}}{1.01^n}$ :
$$
\frac{\dfrac{(n+1)^{100}}{1.01^{n+1}}}
{\dfrac{n^{100}}{1.01^n}}
=\frac{(1+\frac1n)^{100}}
{1.01}
\to 
\frac{1}{1.01}
< 1
$$
This means that the series converges, and so 
$$
\frac{n^{100}}{1.01^n} \to 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

One way to argue that is not quite a valid proof, but gives you an idea of what the limit *ought* to be (and is, in my opinion, the easiest one to do in your head, without writing anything down) is the following: What happens when you double $n$? Well, the numerator is increased by a factor of $2^{100}$, which is quite a lot. However, the denominator is *squared*. To appreciate what that means, go so far out in the sequence that $1.01^n$ is larger than $2^{100}$. It happens quite close to $n = 7000$ (between $n = 6966$ and $n = 6967$, to be specific), so let's say that's where we are.

Now, going from $a_{7000} = \frac{7000^{100}}{1.01^{7000}}$ to $a_{14\,000} = \frac{14\,000^{100}}{1.01^{14\,000}}$ means, as I said above, that the numerator is multiplied by $2^{100}$ and the denominator is multiplied by itself, which is about $2^{100}$ as well (and becomes close to $2^{200}$). That means that these two terms of the sequence are approximately equal. What happens if we double $n$ again, to $28\,000$? The numerator is still multiplied by $2^{100}$, but the denominator is squared, which means that it's multiplied by (about) $2^{200}$. So the value of the fraction decreases by a factor of $2^{100}$. The next doubling of $n$ will decrease the value of the fraction by a factor of $2^{700}$, and so on.

It's pretty clear that this goes toward $0$ as we continue. In order to make it a full proof you have to show that all the terms that we don't talk about go toward $0$ along with the ones we do study. That's a bit more work, and means that this approach probably isn't the best for a full proof.

Answer (score 0):

In all generality,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^ab^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(nb^{n/a}\right)^a=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(nc^n\right)^a=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}nc^n\right)^a,$$ if it exists, with $c:=\sqrt[a]b$.

Then every time you increment $n$, the expression between the parenthesis is multiplied by $$\frac{n+1}nc=\left(1+\frac1n\right)c.$$

The first factor gets closer and closer to $1$ so that in the end $c$ makes the decision.

If $c>1$, the factor is larger than $1$ and the limit goes to infinity.

If $c<1$, the factor will end up being smaller than $1$ and the limit goes to zero.

Then if $c=1$, the limit is just that of $n$.